# How to get today's day of previous month in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a built-in function to get the day in last month,  same as today? Examples:

```
2010/05/02 -> 2010/04/02
2010/05/15 -> 2010/04/15
2010/05/31 -> 2010/04/30
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the criterion for `2010/04/30` being "the same" as `2010/05/31`? :)

Comment: if last month does not have a day number as big as the current month, use the biggest day number for _that_ month. also, leap year should also be considered, i.e. most Feb's last day is 28th, while some is 29th. thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can subtract entire months with `<<`.

```
>> d = Date.parse('2010-05-31')
=> #<Date: 4910695/2,0,2299161>
>> d.to_s
=> "2010-05-31"
>> (d<<1).to_s
=> "2010-04-30"
```

[More info](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Date.html#M000678)

Comment: Nor had I until a few weeks ago. As I'm sure you can tell from the documentation on `Date` there's also a `>>` if you are going in the other direction.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
(Date.today - 1.month).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `<<` operator that @theIV mentioned, but honestly `- 1.month` is more readable.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using

`Time.parse('2010/05/31').months_since(-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could for instance make a time object

```
old_time = Time.now
```

Then create a new time object based on that

```
new_time = Time.local(old_time.year, (old_time.month - 1), old_time.day, old_time.hour, old_time.min, old_time.sec)
```

However, as deceze pointed out, what is the criterion for 5/31 becoming 4/30?
In irb,  4/31 'overflows' to 5/01.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's [date class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html) allows you to add, subtract days from a particular date.